# Power Automate Custom connector Get value from another operation with schema of type object instead of array

Tags: power-automate-custom-connector

I am building a connector which has multiple actions. I am able to use dynamic value and lists but there is a scenario where in Operation1 I need to get value from Operation2 that returns me an Object instead of array. Sample response from Operation 2 is:

{
"success": true,
"data": {
"id": "0187dafe-7378-dbe3-696c-bdb9ec1754f3",
"is_deleted": false,
"modified": "2023-05-02 05:45:21.529068+00:00",
"created": "2023-05-02 05:45:21.529111+00:00",
"lead_process": "https://us-east.api.pipelinersales.com/api/v100/rest/spaces/nv3_PipelinerDev/entities/LeadProcesses/...",
"form_lost_enabled": false,
"is_readonly": false,
"lead_process_id": "9f2dcf79-bc7c-4733-b290-6ed29fb5bb7c"
}
}
}

Thanks alot in advance

from the above response I need to get only lead_process_id. But if I use dynamic values along with list it does not return me anything which is probably because my response schema is of type object. My doubt is can I use dynamic values for such scenario at all or it is only for array i.e., multiple values. if not, what is the alternative. The operation where I need to use lead_process_id is:

- name: lead_process_id
  in: header
  required: true
  type: string
  x-ms-summary: Lead Process ID
  description: Lead Process ID
  x-ms-dynamic-values:
  operationId: LeadTypes.get
  value-path: lead_process_id
  value-title: lead_process_id
  value-collection: data
  parameters:
  service_url:
  parameter: service_url
  space_id:
  parameter: space_id
  id:
  parameter: lead_type_id
  x-ms-dynamic-list:
  operationId: LeadTypes.get
  itemValuePath: lead_process_id
  itemTitlePath: lead_process_id
  itemsPath: data
  parameters:
  service_url:
  parameterReference: service_url
  space_id:
  parameterReference: space_id
  id:
  parameterReference: body/lead_type_id

can someone help me understand if what I am trying to achieve is possible?